# How to resize a iframe inside the containing page?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I want to access the iframe my page is in and resize it. By the way I'm doing it in javascript.

> It's something like parent and height
>   or offsetHeight.

```
<iframe src="mypage.asp" height="400" width="400" ></iframe>
```

And in mypage.asp I do sth similar like this:

```
var h = // new height;
parent.height = h;
```

But it ain't all right? Somebody else who knows more?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this if you want to resize the iframe from within the page that is loaded in your iframe. It seems to work locally at least:

```
function doIt() {
    var elem = window.parent.document.getElementById('myIframe'); // the id of your iframe of course
    elem.style.height = '40em';
}
```

I assume both the page and your iframe are yours and have the same "origin".

Comment: the resizing is actually just elem.height or elem.width.

Comment: I think the element's `height` attribute actually isn't supported (in xhtml at least). Will try too look up some confirmation on that. Anyway, I prefer to do the styling via CSS rules, so that's why I'm manipulating these.

Comment: It is arguably under some circumstaces nicer to add a css-class to it instead of writing to the inline styles. I guess it depends on how "dynamic" one wants the height to be.

Comment: This fails miserably when using cross domain pages.

Comment: Yeah, I did mention the origin restriction:   _I assume both the page and your iframe are yours and have the same "origin"._

Comment: `Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://example.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

Answer (score 4):

I would solve this using [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage). This sends an message from the iframe to the parent page containing the iframe. Then you can update the height in the parent. Trying to set the height from within the iframe gives really nasty browser XSS prevention limitations.

A nice example is [here](http://davidwalsh.name/window-iframe):

parent:

```
// Every two seconds....
setInterval(function() {
    // Send the message "Hello" to the parent window
    // ...if the domain is still "davidwalsh.name"
    parent.postMessage("Hello","http://davidwalsh.name");
},1000);
```

iframe:

```
// Create IE + others compatible event handler
var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[eventMethod];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

// Listen to message from child window
eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
  console.log('parent received message!:  ',e.data);
},false);
```

Comment: Awesome, that works very well, and I notice it is very browser compatible, way back to IE8.